# Conditional Gradle Repositories

Tags: gradle, nexus

We have 2 different ci/cd pipelines. Jenkins is installed on both our company's and the customer's servers. Likewise, we have our own nexus and a separate nexus installed on the customer's servers. Jobs running on our customer's Jenkins agents must connect to the customer's nexus, and when they run on servers at our company, they must connect to our nexus.

What I want to do is actually activate different repository.gradle files with a parameter that I can pass to gradlew. Is something like this possible?

Our `repository.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = 'https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        mavenContent {
            snapshotsOnly()
        }
    }
    maven {
        url = 'https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        mavenContent {
            releasesOnly()
        }
    }

}
```

And what file i wanted to activate on my customers servers `customer-repository.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = 'https://nexus.customer.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        mavenContent {
            snapshotsOnly()
        }
    }
    maven {
        url = 'https://nexus.customer.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        mavenContent {
            releasesOnly()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle files are code written in Groovy, so you have a large deal of flexibility.

Strictly as written, you could do something like this and require `-Pcustomer=true` be added to the Gradle command.

```
if ("${properties["customer"]}" == "true")
    apply from: "repolist1.gradle"
else
    apply from: "repolist2.gradle"
```

However, other approaches often seen are doing string interpolation on the Nexus URL itself:

> `url = 'https://nexus.${properties["customer"] == "true" ? "customer", "company"}.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/'`

Or, perhaps, putting the value in your `~/.gradle/settings.gradle` file and simply reading it from there, without logic in the Gradle file at all, simply set the value you want on each set of machines.